# cakephp how do you call a controller's action inside a model

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, after-save

I'm working within afterSave in my messages model. I'd like to send an email every time a message is created to notify the recepient of their new message. I have an action inside of the messages controller that sends the email and i'd like to call it from afterSave.

I've tried calling it like this:

```
function afterSave($created){
    if($created){
        $this->msgToEmail($this->data);
    }
}
```

i get a sql error because it looks for the function inside of the model instead of the controller.

How do i declare the model function? is it possible?

Comment: you dont! you use model methods inside other models, never ever a controller! so make your code a model method. then you can easily use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use model methods inside other models, never ever a controller!

So make your code a model method. then you can easily use it.

In 1.3 You can hack the component in your model method for now. Until you can finally upgrade to 2.x.

```
App::import('Component', 'Email');
$this->Controller = new Controller();
$this->Email = new EmailComponent(null);
$this->Email->initialize($this->Controller);
// from/to/subject/...
$this->Controller->set('text', $this->data['Model']['content']);
return $this->Email->send();
```

Comment: but how do i handle rendering the view from a model? my variables don't go to the template file when i use $this->set().

Answer (score 1):

To declare a model method, just put it in your model (instead of your controller).

In your Model file:

```
public function msgToEmail($data) {
    // code to send your email...
}
```

Also, don't forget to import `CakeEmail` at the top of your model file:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Comment: Correct! send email in your model it self. Also remove send email code from your controller THAT IS AN ANTI-PATTERN to MVC. I like to create a model specific to sending emails, I just 'import' it in my model where I need.

Comment: i'm using version 1.3 where Email is just a component. App:uses doesn't work for declaring components. If i make an email model won't i still need to access the component somehow?